# Confusion on initialisation in Heap in malloc and New

Tags: c++, c

I have the below codes in C(malloc) and C++(New).I am confused why the C verison is not working.
Error-
memory clobbered before allocated block

`Exited: ExitFailure 127.`

Is there any problems in doing so.

**C++ Version**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char *p=new char[20];
    strcpy(p,"Hello");
    p=(char*)"Hi";
    cout<<p;
    delete p;
}
```

**C version**

```
#include <stdio.h>
# include <malloc.h>
# include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char *p=(char*)malloc(50);
    strcpy(p,"Hello");
    p=(char *)"Hi";
    printf("%s",p);
    free(p);
}
```

Comment: Both are incorrect.  The fact that you had to cast `"Hi"` should be the clue.

Comment: Neither of the versions is correct. `p=(char *)"Hi";` makes `delete` or `free()` behaving undefined.

Comment: Also note that using `new[]` with `delete` is undefined behaviour, so even if you fix the pointer reassignment, it's still bad code.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on implementation details, `malloc` and `new` typically allocate a larger memory segment than requested. Each one of them stores information required for the corresponding `free` and `delete` in that additional piece of memory and then returns to the user a pointer to the memory that comes **after** that piece.

When `free` and `delete` are called, each one of them expects to find the required information **before** the address of the memory that the user has requested to deallocate. If that information is corrupted (or in your example - completely invalid), then undefined behavior is invoked, and at that point anything could happen.

Answer (score 1):

```
char *p=(char*)malloc(50); // you allocate p
strcpy(p,"Hello");        // you change the p's value in legal way
                         // here should be free(p)
p=(char *)"Hi";         // YOU OVERWRITE p, YOU CAN'T FREE IT AFTER THAT LINE
printf("%s",p);        //
free(p);              // this line should be removed
```

Also:

```
char *p=new char[20];
strcpy(p,"Hello");
/*here should be delete[] p, not delete p, it deletes only 1 element
 *you allocated 20
 */
p=(char*)"Hi";
cout<<p;
delete p; //this line should be removed
```

Comment: I think that you're explain to OP what he or she already knows. The question implies that OP knows it's wrong and not supposed to work, but then OP is asking how come the "C behavior" is different from the "C++ behavior".